# Translating "to open up" and "closed" (revealing feelings to another)

Tags: traducción

In English, "to open (oneself) up to someone" describes someone who shares their feelings and emotions with another person as opposed to someone who is "closed" and keeps their feelings to themselves?

What is the best way in Spanish to express this meaning of "open", "closed", and "to open up to someone"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The straight translation is correct: 'abrirse', 'ser una persona abierta' and 'cerrarse', 'ser una persona cerrada'. Other expressions are 'introvertido' and 'extrovertido', which have their own English translations.

One special case is with 'close', that in spanish can be translated both as 'cerrado/a' and 'cercano/a'. The latter, when applied to persons, means the contrary than the former and is more related to 'open personality'.